# Harmful to NPN transistor if collector circuit is broken?

Tags: current, npn

Is there any harm to having a conventional switch that can open the circuit between the collector and +V with an NPN transistor? While the base is still being excited by a pin of my controller?

I am using a simple circuit to allow a micro controller to switch a light on and off. If it matters, the transistor in question is a TIP31 I found at Radio Shack.

Comment: Be sure base current is below max spec. Beome acquainted with MOSFETS at some stage. Very easy to drive."Logic leveL" Fts can be driven from 5V or possibly less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem at all. The transistor 'degrades' to being a simple diode which receives some modest (I assume!) current from your controller.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I thought it should be okay but wanted to check, as it would be a shame to put this project together and then have it fail in a short time due to incompetent design…

Answer (score 1):

Typically, disconnecting the collector from a transistor will be harmless, but that isn't always the case.  Consider an NPN transitor with the emitter tied to ground through a 5ohm resistor and the base tied to a "rigid" 10-volt supply and the collector either attached to a "rigid" 15-volt supply or disconnected.  With the collector connected, the emitter would be about 8-9 volts above ground (dropping 8-9 volts in the resistor), and the emitter current would be about 1.6-1.8 amps.  Most of this would be supplied from the collector, and the transistor would be operating well within its collector-current (and total-power-dissipation) specifications.

With the collector disconnected, the emitter would still be about 8-9 volts above ground, and the emitter current would be about the same, but all the entire 1.6+ amps would be flowing into the base, which has an Absolute Maximum Rating of 1.0 amps.

It's doubtful that a typical microcontroller circuit would be capable of driving enough current into the transistor base to cause damage, but some other circuits would use transistors in such a way that a disconnecting the collector from a transistor could damage the base.