# How do I tell if a transistor is bad?

Tags: current, npn

I have just had a frustrating experience with an NPN transistor that came from a pack of 15 "switching transistors" from Radio Shack. The specs on the packaging say "Typical hfe: 200" but when I measure and calculate the values from an actual operating circuit it looks like the hfe is more like 8. (If I am calculating correctly, 35ma measured on the base is allowing only 280ma to flow.)

Is it possible this transistor was simply damaged by ESD or something?

I am fairly confident my circuit is sound, because when I replace the transistor with a different type (and changed my base resistor appropriately) the circuit functions fine.

Comment: IF this is a TIP 31 (and you really really should give us the whole circuit and component details, then pinout is at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: TIP31 doesn't make sense for this.  It is a medium power transistor in a TO-220 package.  Even it's typical gain is well below 200, and "switching transistor" is not a reasonable classification.

Comment: The TIP31 was "thrown in" as a test to determine if my circuit would work with a different transistor. And it did, but you are absolutely right the gain is not what I want for the finished circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You MAY have collector and emitter reversed.

If you swap C and E you will usually get a functioning transistor with much lower hfe and generally poorer characteristics.

Transistor pinouts come in all possible variants.

Simple test jig:

On a breadboard where a device can be plugged in -

- Connect collector via 10k to V+ (say 12V)
- Connect base via 1 megohm to V+
- Connect emitter to ground.
- Measure drop across Collector resistor = proportional to collector current.

Now swap C & E and repeat. A large  difference in current gain will be

evident.

BUT many DMMs (test meters) have transistor testers built in. Assume C&E. Test. Swap assumed C&E. Test again.

---

For leaded "jellybean" transistors I use BC337-40 transistors. In modest volume they can often be got for as little as most other sorts and they are excellent for most uses. 500 mA Ic, hfe of 200-600 (from memory).

---

IF this is a TIP 31 (and you really really should give us the whole circuit and component details) then this is the pinout:

[image]

Comment: I am looking for a convenient way to draw simple circuits like this, but my circuit isn't far from the classic test circuit shown below. Just replace R2 with a lantern bulb that needs 700ma or so.

Answer (score 3):

Whoa, you put 35 mA on the base and were looking for 35mA x 200 = 7.0A of collector current!!?  If so, that transistor is probably toast now.  Since you said "switching transistor", I'm assuming something in a TO-92 case, not a power case, right?

Try to set things up for the collector current to be around 20 mA.  That would mean around 100 µA base current.  Here is a simple test circuit:

[image]

R1 will allow about 100 µA to flow into the base.  That times the gain of 200 should result in about 20 mA collector current.  The ammeter is there to measure the actual collector current.  R2 is only there for protection.  In case the gain of the transistor is a lot higher than the specified minimum (not at all unusual), you don't want to blow up the transistor with excessive collector current like you did the first one.  R2 will limit the collector current to a bit under 50 mA no matter what else is going on.  You didn't provide specs for the transistor, but 50 mA is most likely OK.  If the meter reads 40 mA or more, then the circuit could be bottoming out, in which case you have to try again with a larger base resistor until the meter reads less than 40 mA.

Once you find a operating point this method can measure well, meaning 5-40 mA collector current, you can connect the top end of R2 directly to the 5V supply and measure the voltage on the base.  That should be around 600-700 mV.  The 5V supply minus the base voltage is the drop accross R1, from which you can calculate the base current.  Gain is then simply collector current divided by base current.

Comment: In [this current question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23327/harmful-to-npn-transistor-if-collector-circuit-is-broken) he mentions a TIP31 "which he got from Radio Shack" which changes perspective slightly. Base current abs max for [TIP31](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/TI/TIP31C.pdf) is 1 Amp so his toast should be only a very very light brown.

Comment: I didn't start with that voltage… That's just what I stopped at as it was too close to the 40ma max for the PIC controller pin to experiment further. The TIP31 was what I replaced the transistor in question with, and it worked flawlessly in the same circuit (after changing the base resistor appropriately). Thanks for the info on how to test it out, etc!